# what is basename(__FILE__) === basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])?

Tags: php, basename

I am working on a PHP code, I saw the following code in the connect.php file

```
if (basename(__FILE__) === basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
   header("Location: https://example.com/");
   exit();
}
```

This lines are written on the first line of the file, before even making any include, I think it has to do with the http.
Can you tell me what is the programmer trying to do here? I am new to PHP, so please provide a source if you have.

Answer (score 1):

This code is set "Location" http header in the web-server response which redirects the client to the "https://example.com" and interrupt the execution of the script.

It happens only if the file `connect.php` requested directly, i.e not included from another one.

I believe this code might be written in order to prevent any dangerous requests to be processed.

Comment: So, this is to prevent users from reaching the website using http, and to prevent them from reaching the connect.php directly?

Comment: That's right. I assume `connect.php` is used for establishing a connection with database and it is supposed to be included from different files.

Comment: Yes, that is true. connect.php is used for establishing a connection with database, and is included from different files.

Thank you Ilya